# How do you repeat similar elements multiple times with different content using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a website with a meet the team page, and it's a hassle to write the same paragraph tags and classes over and over again. I was wondering if there is any faster way to get this done, kind of like a function, where I just input the name and position of the person and I get a fully formatted addition to the HTML. Any help would be appreciated!

I'm using Bootstrap 4, if that helps.

Comment: You are basically asking how a dynamic content page works. Look into server side or client side templating. Then all you need to do is store the basic team data

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about what you want to do if you want to get an answer here, I'm sorry to say. If you're doing it client side, it probably involves an array of data, a map function, and `innerHTML`, but you need to try something yourself first, then come back here if you're having problems.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I'll try to learn more about all the things mentioned.

Comment: Sorry about that! I might have done that by accident; I meant to accept it, and just changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript to create multiple HTML elements with the same `classList`. It's now up to you to adapt this for your context:

```js
const $root = document.getElementById('root')

const data = ["foo", "bar", "naz"]

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var newEl = document.createElement('p')
  newEl.classList = 'data-item'
  newEl.innerText = data[i]
  $root.appendChild(newEl)
}
```

```css
.data-item {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```